# How to get set of specific cells from Dataset in RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have one textbox for generating letter. In my dataset we have multiple rows, by using `First(..)` we'll get my value from the very first row field. But some of the values are in different rows and I want to use those fields value in my expression of textbox to create content of letter.

Dataset structure has 3 columns `Name, Head, Amount` . I'll get the name by using `First(Name)` but `Amount` value is available in different rows.

How can I use multiple `Amount` values in my text expression.

My dataset has following values:

```
 Name  |  Amount | Head
 ABC   |  500    | First
 ABC   |  600    | Second
```

My text expression is:

```
We are pleased to inform Mr. [First(Name)] is winner of our quiz 
and won __Amount1___  and __Amount2__ amount as prize.
```

Here in above content I want to fill `Amount1` with `500` and `Amount2` with `600`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't so a simple solution could be creating a table group by `Name` and put `Amounts` in details.

The output will be:

```
We are pleased to inform Mr. ABC is winner of our quiz and won these amounts as prize:
500
600
```

[image: table group and expression]

Note that if you don't need to print a report containing multiple `Name` you could also use a `ReportParameter` to send a string (easily build using .NET code) with multiple amounts to your report.